# R- SQLDF - SELECT ... CASE... END

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf

**Hello, 
I am trying to run a query that use a CASE statement from R. I am using the SQLDF package. The same query works fine in Mysql. The query gives the values of 0 or 1 to "express" according to the following situations:**

Select "express" =
CASE
when  E_MAIL like "%gmail%" then 1
when  E_MAIL like "%yahoo%" then 1
when  E_MAIL like "%hotmail%" then   1
else 0
END 
from data
 ;

**This is what I have tried in R:**
alpha<-sqldf( "Select "express"=
CASE
when  E_MAIL like "%gmail%" then 1
when  E_MAIL like "%yahoo%" then 1
when  E_MAIL like "%hotmail%" then   1
else 0
END
from data");

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are that the query string in the question has quotes within quotes and the syntax is wrong.  Using the default SQLite database (sqldf also supports MySQL) we have:

```
library(sqldf)
data <- data.frame(E_MAIL = c("x@x.com", "x@yahoo.com"))

sqldf("select E_MAIL,
  case
    when E_MAIL like '%gmail%' then 1
    when E_MAIL like '%yahoo%' then 1
    when E_MAIL like '%hotmail%' then 1
    else 0
  end express
  from data")
```

giving:

```
       E_MAIL express
1     x@x.com       0
2 x@yahoo.com       1
```

Or, perhaps you meant to perform an udpate.  This gives the same output with the test data shown:

```
data <- data.frame(E_MAIL = c("x@x.com", "x@yahoo.com"), express = 0)

sqldf(c("update data set express = 
  case
    when E_MAIL like '%gmail%' then 1
    when E_MAIL like '%yahoo%' then 1
    when E_MAIL like '%hotmail%' then 1
    else 0
  end", "select * from main.data"))
```

**Note:** Next time please provide a complete reproducible example including input.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck , how do you handle if the criteria on the when is a set of values and you can not use a like .. i.e. WHEN column in <set of values> and the set is like this c('China','Hong','Taiwan')

Comment: If these are exact matches you can create a new data frame from the keywords and join it to the larger data frame or if there are only a few keywords use the sql `in` construct.